# Core Data Fetch Request Error

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, core-data

I am trying to fetch record based on attribute name.

I also try to search similar issue but I am not able to find solution so I am posting question ...

but I got exception while fetching:

```
[error] error: exception handling request: <NSSQLFetchRequestContext: 0x1c019a270> , keypath audio_1.m4a not found in entity <NSSQLEntity answer id=8> with userInfo of (null)
CoreData: error: exception handling request: <NSSQLFetchRequestContext: 0x1c019a270> , keypath audio_1.m4a not found in entity <NSSQLEntity answer id=8> with userInfo of (null)
2017-09-28 19:03:36.725060+0530 app[9684:891158] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'keypath audio_1.m4a not found in entity <NSSQLEntity answer id=8>'
```

My code :

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: Entity)

    if let predic = predicate_str{
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: predic)
        fetchRequest.predicate=predicate
    }

    do {
        let arr = try appsession.managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest) //CRASHED


        // success ...
    } catch let error as NSError {
        // failure
        print("Fetch failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return(nil,error)
    }
```

**Thank you,**

Comment: What is `predicate_str`? What is `Entity`?

Comment: @jrturton,  Entity is "answer" & predicate_str = "imagePath LIKE[c] audio_1.m4a"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're building your predicate string incorrectly. Values to match have to be inside quotes, so you'd want to build it like this:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K LIKE[c] %@", "imagePath", "audio1.m4a")
```

Which resolves to the following predicate string:

```
imagePath LIKE[c] "audio1.m4a"
```

Note the quotes around the value you're matching, and the lack of quotes around the attribute name. Your current predicate is trying to find a record whose `imagePath` attribute has the same value as its `audio1.m4a` attribute, which doesn't work.